# JQuery Post return values containing spaces problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I’m using php/jQuery/Ajax to post user data entry both new records and updating existing records.
No problem with any of that except for the re-editing of newly created record.

The edit/add new feature opens a modal form and if the record is an existing one, the fields on the form are populated by values in the data-record-info attribute of the item that was clicked (Blank if new). The user edits the form and posts the data to the MySQL database on form submit. The returned string from the $.post(url) updates the values in the GUI and also the data-record-info attribute.

The newly updated data-record-info attribute looks like this if it’s an existing record:-

```
Data-record-info=‘{“id”:”encryped_id”,”Field_1”:”text with spaces”}’
```

The problem arises if the record is new. The return string, although apparently identical to the return string on existing records, fails to update the data-record-info attribute if there are any spaces in the string. The newly updated data-record-info attribute looks like this if it’s a new record:-

```
Data-record-info=‘{“id”:”encryped_id”,”Field_1”:”text” =“” “with”=“” “spaces”}=“”’
```

Comment: The question does not contain enough information to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem.  It also does not clearly state what the problem is; "fails to update" is vague.

Comment: Yes you are correct Scott, “fails to update” is vague but that it only part of the sentence which I wrote. The full sentence said “fails to update the data-record-info attribute if there are any spaces”. I think that is quite accurate in terms of an explanation as to what the problem is.

Comment: Fails to update how?  Is there an error from MySQL?  If so, what is it?  What SQL query is being run to perform the update?

Comment: I’m sorry Scott, I’m doing all of this from my iPhone at the moment so can’t post the full code until I’m back at my desk. I thought I had asked the question and provided enough info. There is no issue with the sql update, the issue is the updating of the data-record-info attribute of the item that was clicked.